# Angular 7 site "can't be reached" after connecting to VPN

Tags: angular, proxy, windows-10, vpn, lan

At my job we need to use Pulse VPN to connect to internal websites. When I connect it breaks my angular site.

I have noticed that it also breaks all external websites, but that can be fixed by turning off `Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Use a proxy server for your LAN`. This setting gets turned on every time the VPN connects. Turning it off allows internal and external websites to connect, but some how is blocking my localhost:4200 angular website.

When I try to connect I'm shown Chrome's `This site can't be reached (localhost took too long to respond)` page with suggestions to `Check the proxy and firewall`. Windows Network Diagnostic says:  `The remote device or resource won't accept the connection`

Other things I've tried:

- running via `ng serve -o --host 0.0.0.0`
- Hard refresh, clearing cache, emptying localhost application data
- Hard exit from Chrome using the Task Manager and restarting the app
- Run `ipconfig` in cmd, get the IPv4 Address. Go to $IPv4Address:4200. This works! The client angular site loads. BUT 
  requests receive the error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/API_ROUTE' from origin 'http://LOCAL_IP:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy`. If I go to the localhost API route in the browser directly it loads fine.

Comment: Can you please try to serve the app using ng serve -o --host 0.0.0.0 and see if it works?

Comment: Good idea but that unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Are you trying to access it from the same machine? Please clarify the senario

Comment: Yes I'm running the site locally in VS Code and trying to access it on the same laptop

Comment: Just discovered I can get Angular SPA loading by visiting my local IP:4200, but its connection to the local API server on port :80 is broken. No data can be fetched, which causes errors that prevent the page from loading. Any idea how to fix that? Wow and localhost:80/API_ROUTE is working fine

Comment: what api you using?

Comment: Custom API, written in C#

Comment: Somewhere you're telling Angular how to connect to the API, right? Try telling it to go to `http://$IPv4Address/API_ROUTE`. This sounds more like a networking question than a development question though...

Comment: Most VPNs don't route localhost properly in the vpn tunnel, if at all, due to a conflict between what "localhost" actually means coming from the vpn. Particularly with multiple users on a vpn, what does `localhost` mean in that scenario? Your machine? Another users? The VPN itself? The server it is running on?

Comment: Go to your api project, then right click properties, in the web section, in servers, put in the dropdown you have 3 choices, local IIS, IIS express, and external host. Select Local IIS, name it how you want, and the press create virtual directory.

Comment: The comment I put before should make it run wherever, and whoever got your IP can access it.

Comment: Ohhhh, have you configured CORS in the WebApiConfig.cs file??

Comment: @Monkey - I tried that but instead of opening the API im expecting it shows a Chrome login prompt and then kicks me out. The same thing happens if I navigate to the url directly, but `localhost/API_ROUTE` works strangely enough. @Josh that makes a lot of sense, but is confusing to me why the server works on localhost. @Condor I will try your suggestion, but I think I'm going to try to figure out how to edit the CORS values on the server first.

Comment: If you want I can show you a sample

Comment: It's all setup I just have to append my machine's IP to the list. Gimme a minute

Comment: Ok so I'm debugging the server but it's not hitting a breakpoint where I set CORS. The code is: `var origins = LOAD_CORS();` `origins += ",http://LOCAL_IP:4200/";` `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*");` Am I appending my local machine correctly? I rebuild and reload my site and it's not connecting (but loading the API route in browser URL still works)

Comment: IT WORKS! Just had to remove `/` at end of my origin and then restart IIS a couple times

Answer (score 0):

In the comments @Josh says that localhost routing can get messed up by VPNs. For me, my angular site wasn't working at `localhost:4200` but my API was at `localhost:80`.

To fix this I found my machine's IP and visited it directly. On windows run `ipconfig` in a cmd terminal, then copy the `IPv4 Address` into the browser: `$IPv4Address:4200`. The Angular site loads!

Unfortunately my local server's CORS settings were not configured to accept connections from this host string. I'm using C# and edited the `WebApiConfig.cs` file to look like this:

```
  var origins = LOAD_ORIGINS_STRING();
  origins += ",http://$IPv4Address:4200";
  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*");
```

Then I restarted my (IIS) server to apply the new settings. Be sure there is no `/` or other text after the port number in your new origin. And then it worked! It may not be solving the underlying problem, but it's a solid workaround for me.